# Flutter google maps custom icon

Tags: flutter

I can't seem to work out how to use custom icons in my app. Nothing I have tried so far have worked. Below is my relevant code. The problem I have is that the customIcon variable seems to be null and the default code is kicking in as you can see in addMarker code. Im using a Set to put my markers into. Im also creating a customIcon with async method and are running them in the initState method. Can you please take a look and provide me with some help would be much appriciated!

```
@override
  void initState() {
    //customIcon1 = setCustom();
    setCustomIcon();
    print('CustomIcon is: ${customIcon.toString()}');
    _addMarker();
    super.initState();
  }

  //TODO Custom Icon is null I have to get this to work somehow!
  setCustomIcon() async {
    customIcon = await BitmapDescriptor.fromAssetImage(
        ImageConfiguration(devicePixelRatio: 2.5),
        'images/image1.png');
  }

void _addMarker() {
    setState(() {
      _markers!.add(Marker(
          markerId: MarkerId('1'),
          //icon: customIcon!,
          icon: customIcon ??
              BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarkerWithHue(BitmapDescriptor.hueYellow),
          position: LatLng(59.36492713861164, 18.063758410239704),
          //59.3293, 18.0686
          infoWindow: InfoWindow(
            title: 'title 1',
            snippet: 'test 1',
          )));
      _markers!.add(Marker(
          markerId: MarkerId('2'),
          //icon: customIcon!,
          icon:
              BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarkerWithHue(BitmapDescriptor.hueYellow),
          position: LatLng(58.17027695163088, 13.618293330200967),
          //59.3293, 18.0686
          infoWindow: InfoWindow(
            title: 'title 2',
            snippet: 'test 2',
          )));
    });
  }


body: GoogleMap(
        myLocationButtonEnabled: false,
        zoomControlsEnabled: false,
        initialCameraPosition: _initialCameraPosition,
        onMapCreated: (controller) => _googleMapController = controller,
        markers: {
          //Iterate with get over all the markers in the Set instead of this!
          _markers!.elementAt(0), _markers!.elementAt(1),
          
        },
```

Comment: Did you try to call  _addMarker(); before setting a custom icon? Like this 

 super.initState();
    _addMarker();
    setCustomIcon();

Comment: Yes, its unfortunatly the same error.

Comment: Try the below answer. Hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

Try these steps:

- Get user location (if required)
- Add Markers
- Set custom Icon

  ```
  class MapHome extends StatefulWidget {
                 List<BarData> mapData = []; //Array List
                 Map visitData;
                 MapHome(this.mapData, this.visitData, {Key? 
                 key}) : super(key: key);

                 @override
                 _MapHomeState createState() => _MapHomeState();
               }

               class _MapHomeState extends State<MapHome> {
               //MARK: - Variables & Constants
                 final _mapHomeScaffKey = 
                 GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
                 GoogleMapController? _controller;
                 Set<Marker> _markers = {};
                 BitmapDescriptor? customIcon;
                 bool isLoading = false;
                 final List<LatLng> nearbyCarsLocation = [];
                 LocationData? _currentPosition;
                 String? _address, _dateTime;
                 Location location = Location();

               //MARK: - Arrays & Dictionaries

               //MARK: -View LifeCycle
                 @override
                 void initState() {
                   super.initState();
                   setState(() {
                     isLoading = true;
                   });
                   getLoc(context);
                 }

                 @override
                 void dispose() {
                   _controller!.dispose();
                   super.dispose();
                 }

                 Future<void> _onMapCreated(GoogleMapController 
                 controller) async {
               // ignore: prefer_conditional_assignment
                   if (_currentPosition == null) {
                     _currentPosition = await 
                    location.getLocation();
                   }
                   setState(() {
                     _controller = controller;
                     for (var mapDetails in widget.mapData) {
                       setState(() {
                         nearbyCarsLocation.add(LatLng(
                double.parse(mapDetails.latitude.toString()),
             double.parse(mapDetails.longitude.toString())));
                       });
                     }
                   });
                   _addMarkers();
                 }

                 getLoc(BuildContext context) async {
                   bool _serviceEnabled;
                   PermissionStatus _permissionGranted;
                   _serviceEnabled = await location.serviceEnabled();
                   if (!_serviceEnabled) {
                     _serviceEnabled = await location.requestService();
                     if (!_serviceEnabled) {
                       return;
                     }
                   }

                   _permissionGranted = await location.hasPermission();
                   if (_permissionGranted == PermissionStatus.denied) {
                     _permissionGranted = await location.requestPermission();
                     if (_permissionGranted != PermissionStatus.granted) {
                       return;
                     }
                   }

                   _currentPosition = await location.getLocation();
                   DateTime now = DateTime.now();
                   var _dateTime = DateFormat('EEE d MMM kk:mm:ss ').format(now);
                   if (_currentPosition != null) {
                     setState(() {
                       isLoading = false;
                     });
                     _addMarkers();
                     _setCustomMarker();
                   } else {
                     setState(() {
                       isLoading = false;
                     });
                   }
                 }

                 @override
                 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
                   return SafeArea(
                       child: Scaffold(
                     appBar: AppBar(
                         toolbarHeight: 60.0,
                         titleSpacing: 0.5,
                         // automaticallyImplyLeading: true,
                         leading: GestureDetector(
                           onTap: () {
                             Navigator.pop(context);
                           },
                           child: Padding(
                             padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                             child: Image.asset(
                               Commons.assetPath + "icon_arrow_back.png",
                             ),
                           ),
                         ),
                         title: const Text(
                           'Map',
                           textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                           style: TextStyle(
                             color: Colors.white,
                             fontSize: 18.0,
                             fontFamily: Commons.fontFamily,
                             fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                           ),
                         ),
                         actions: <Widget>[
                           Padding(
                             padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5.0, 5.0, 12.0, 5.0),
                             child: Row(
                               mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                               crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                               children: [
                                 GestureDetector(
                                   onTap: () {
                                   },
                                   child: Padding(
                                     padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0),
                                     child: Image.asset(
                                       Commons.assetPath + 'icon_search.png',
                                       height: 20.0,
                                       width: 20.0,
                                     ),
                                   ),
                                 ),
                               ],
                             ),
                           ),
                         ]),
                     key: _mapHomeScaffKey,
                     body: isLoading == true
                         ? SpinKitSpinningLines(
                             color: HexColor('#2a48ae'),
                             itemCount: 7,
                           )
                         : Stack(children: <Widget>[
                             GoogleMap(
                               onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,
                               initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
                                 target: LatLng(_currentPosition!.latitude!,
                                     _currentPosition!.longitude!),
                                 zoom: 12,
                               ),
                               buildingsEnabled: true,
                               indoorViewEnabled: true,
                               myLocationEnabled: true,
                               myLocationButtonEnabled: true,
                               mapType: MapType.normal,
                               markers: _markers,
                             )
                           ]),
                   ));
                 }

                 //MARK: - Class Methods
                 void _setCustomMarker() async {
                   final Uint8List markerIcon =
                       await getBytesFromAsset(Commons.assetPath + 'map_marker.png', 70);
                   customIcon = BitmapDescriptor.fromBytes(markerIcon);
                   // customIcon = await BitmapDescriptor.fromAssetImage(
                   //     const ImageConfiguration(size: Size(2.0, 2.0)), Commons.assetPath + 'map_marker.png');
                 }

                 Future<Uint8List> getBytesFromAsset(String path, int width) async {
                   ByteData data = await rootBundle.load(path);
                   ui.Codec codec = await ui.instantiateImageCodec(data.buffer.asUint8List(),
                       targetWidth: width);
                   ui.FrameInfo fi = await codec.getNextFrame();
                   return (await fi.image.toByteData(format: ui.ImageByteFormat.png))!
                       .buffer
                       .asUint8List();
                 }

                 void _addMarkers() {
                   setState(() {
                     debugPrint(nearbyCarsLocation.toString());
                     for (var i = 0; i < nearbyCarsLocation.length; i++) {
                       var now = DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch;
                       _markers.add(Marker(
                           markerId:
                               MarkerId(nearbyCarsLocation[i].toString() + now.toString()),
                           position: nearbyCarsLocation[i],
                           onTap: () {
                           },
                           icon: customIcon!
                           ));
                     }
                   });
                 }
               }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

I did manage to solve it with a Futurebuilder. First I crated a Future function that checked for customIcons, if they were true (not null), then this is the relevant code from the build method:

```
    return FutureBuilder<bool>(
            //If _prepareWidget returns true we are good to go and the icons are not null
            future: _prepareWidget(),
            builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<bool> snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                return Scaffold(
               .........
             body: GoogleMapWidget(
                  
                  initialCameraPosition: _initialCameraPosition,
                  controller: controller,
                  
                  markers: getMarker()),   
                } else {
            return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          }  
              
class GoogleMapWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const GoogleMapWidget(
      {Key? key,
      required CameraPosition initialCameraPosition,
      required this.controller,
      this.customIcon,
      this.markers})
      : _initialCameraPosition = initialCameraPosition,
        super(key: key);

  final CameraPosition _initialCameraPosition;
  final controller;
  final BitmapDescriptor? customIcon;
  final markers;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GoogleMap(
      myLocationButtonEnabled: false,
      zoomControlsEnabled: false,
      initialCameraPosition: _initialCameraPosition,
      onMapCreated: controller!,
      markers: markers,
```